# How do i check the registered email id had given access to my app?

Tags: php, rest, google-api

My mobile app allows sign in only through google. when new users comes in and authenticating by google then i create a new entry in my db with info got from google.

I want to check with google api from server side where the registered email id has given access to my app or not.

The reason am asking this question to allow only google users who authenticated my app can access the data. now insertion happens through api even if i send any data with curl request with proper parameters. so i need a way to find legit users

This is the code for client side login.

```
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
  var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
  console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); 
  var user_name = profile.getName();
  var user_image = profile.getImageUrl();
  var user_email = profile.getEmail();
  googleUser.disconnect()
  allow_login(user_name,user_image,user_email);
```

}

```
function allow_login(user_name,user_image,user_email) {
  var inputs = {'username' : user_name, 'user_image' : user_image, 'user_email' : user_email };
  $.ajax({
        url : "login_request.php",
        type : "POST",
        data : inputs,
        dataType : "json",
        success : function(response){
          alert(response.message);
        }

      });
```

}

Comment: can you please provide the code (best with included responses from google) of what you're doing right now?

Comment: I have update the question with code. i am looking for server side script where it interacts with google api with the email i stored in db and returns me whether that email id has given access to my app or not..

Comment: You need a way of verifying this without querying google from the server side. What google-api are you using?